# I query the collection ".where" and get the document ID,And I want to delete it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote the following code.
However, when I run it, it does not work.
I am probably not able to get the document ID.
sorry,Please let me know if there are any modifications to my code.

```
 Future<void> deleteRoom() async {

//Put the ID of the document to be deleted in the list
        List deleteRoomIdList = []; 

//The ID of the document to be deleted is placed here in a for statement.
        String deleteId;

    
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('room')
            .where('roomCount', whereIn: [0, null])
            .get()
            .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
                  querySnapshot.docs.forEach(
                    (doc) {
                      deleteRoomIdList.add(doc.id);
                    },
                  ),
                });

    //Deleting with a for statement
        for (deleteId in deleteRoomIdList) {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('room')
              .doc(deleteId)
              .delete();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up `.then()` and `await` patterns. Don't do this, it's confusing. In your case, you missed that the statment getting the ids is not done yet when you start deleteing. Pick one and stick with it. Personally, I think async/await makes for cleaner code:

```
Future<void> deleteRoom() async {
    final deleteRoomIdList = []; 

    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('room')
        .where('roomCount', whereIn: [0, null])
        .get();

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) { deleteRoomIdList.add(doc.id); });

    for (final deleteId in deleteRoomIdList) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('room')
          .doc(deleteId)
          .delete();
    }
  }
```